# Pass Column names for a Select Query to retrieve from temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I had a temporary table that contains the column names that I want to retrieve from the specific table (table A).

Here's the sample code:

```
Declare @temp table (ColumnNames varchar(30))

insert into @temp 
values('Name'), ('Class'), ('School')

--select Query to retrieve only name,class and School columns
end
```

Here table A contains more than 10 columns

Comment: You basically have to use dynamic SQL to construct a string that has the `select` you want.  Then you can use `sp_executesql` to execute it.

Comment: Even am going to use this in Store Procedure only. need some piece of code to go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you asked for:

```
Declare @temp table (ColumnNames varchar(30))

insert into @temp 
values('Id'), ('Name')

DECLARE @ColumnNames nvarchar(max)

SELECT @ColumnNames = stuff((SELECT ',' + ColumnNames 
FROM @temp
FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '')

EXEC (N'SELECT ' + @ColumnNames + N' FROM TheTable')
```

But something is fundamentally wrong with this. Why on Earth you need to store column names in a table variable and later read it to build the sql statement?

Comment: Thanks for your answer..., working fine. am working on it because user selects the column names which he like to see at GUI, that's the reason am working on it.

Comment: There are better alternatives, for example building the sql statement at t client side. Passing the columnNames in a XML parameter, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQLTOEXECUTE VARCHAR(MAX),
           @Col VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE CURSOR curs FOR 
SELECT ColumnNames FROM @temp

SET @SQLTOEXECUTE = 'SELECT '

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM Curs
INTO @Col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
   SET @SQLTOEXECUTE = @SQLTOEXECUTE + @Col + ', '

   FETCH NEXT FROM Curs
   INTO @Col
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs

SET @SQLTOEXECUTE = ' FROM <Table name goes here>' 
PRINT @SQLTOEXECUTE
```

This should get you going